# SerialPort write and read data without DataReceived EventHandler

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to process the direct response of the data I send over SerialPort and show the result. It is not convenient for me to receive using SerialPort's DataReceived event. Because I need to process the incoming message in forms inside the main form, not on the main form. That's why I have to write and read. However, after writing in the code I use, BytesToRead always returns 0 at the while(serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) step and does not enter this step. If I add while(true) to the beginning, it waits until the timeout comes, sometimes it reads, but data is lost. How can I get the response after simply doing Serial.write(data,0,data.count)?

```
        newBytetoString = new List<byte>();
        var dataString = "#45M*";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
        

        try
        {
            _serialPort.Write(data.ToArray(), 0, data.ToArray().Count());

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {

            byte[] inbuffer = new byte[1];
            List<byte> bytesReceived = new List<byte>();
            List<byte> responseReceived = new List<byte>();

            System.Timers.Timer _responseTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

            _responseTimer.Interval = 5000;



            _responseTimer.Elapsed += ResponseTimer_Elapsed;
            _responseTimer.AutoReset = false;
            _responseTimer.Start();



            while (!_responseTimedOut)
            {
                
                while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    var byteRead = _serialPort.Read(inbuffer, 0, inbuffer.Length);

                    bytesReceived.Add(inbuffer[0]);
                    responseReceived.Add(inbuffer[0]);


                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                }
                else _responseTimedOut = true;
            }
            _responseTimer.Stop();
            _responseTimedOut = false;

            //_serialPort.Close();
            //_serialPort.Dispose();

            return bytesReceived.ToArray();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this could be an alternative. [PInvokeSerialPort 1.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvokeSerialPort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use the DataReceived event and you want to simply write a message and then read you can use code similar to below:

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort.Open();

// Write data to the serial port
string data = "Hello, World!";
serialPort.Write(data);

// Read data from the serial port
string receivedData = serialPort.ReadExisting();
Console.WriteLine($"Received data: {receivedData}");

serialPort.Close();
```

The [ReadExisting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) function will reads all the data currently available in the input buffer of the serial port and returns it as a string.

If you are still getting issues seeing data come back I would refer to the documentation on you device and make sure you have setup the correct com port settings (baud rate, etc). Hope this helps.

Comment: my code is working. There was a read function in the Thread that I started in Class before, so there was no response to the request I sent. overlooked. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working